# PHP to list files in directory

Tags: php

I'm trying to use some of the php examples here on S.O. to list the files in a directory as links on a web page.  Here is the code I am using:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$directory = "/home/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.html");
foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
echo "<a href=$phpfile>".basename($phpfile)."</a>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the only thing that shows on the displayed page is:

> ".basename($phpfile).""; } ?>

Comment: PHP is not enabled on your server.

Comment: It's as @meagar says. Tip: On the command line you can always quickly verify that it's no syntax error by doing `php5 -l yourfile.php`.

Comment: Or no server is running, and you have attempted to read this file in the browser from the filesystem, rather than from a web server.

Comment: This behaviour means the script is not executed but displayed. @meagar you should consider writing your comment as an answer.

Comment: If you 'view source' in your browser, you'll probably see the whole PHP file as it is written above. That would support @meagar's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file is not being run by a PHP interpreter before being sent to the browser, meaning the PHP code as posted is being interpreted by the browser as HTML. In the following segment of your code, everything between the opening `<` and closing `>` is being interpreted as a single tag and not rendered:

```
<?php
$directory = "/home/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/";
$phpfiles = glob($directory . "*.html");
foreach($phpfiles as $phpfile)
{
echo "<a href=$phpfile>
```

This could be happening for several reasons:

- PHP is not installed or not properly configured on your server
- You are accessing the file directly from your local filesystem instead of through a PHP-enabled web server